# JQuery Cross-slide

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to cycle through 3 images with JQuery Cross-slide, but the images doesn't want to display, here is the basic code below.

All 3 images are in 650 - 100 size, and they are in the correct location, but the images just don't want to display. What am i doing wrong??

```
<html>

<body>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="jquery.cross-slide.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<div id="crossslide" style="width:650px; height:100px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<!--
$(function(){
    $("#crossslide").crossSlide({
      speed: 45,
      fade:  1
    }, [
      { src: "01.jpg",    dir:"up"},
      { src: "02.jpg",    dir:"down"},
      { src: "03.jpg",    dir:"left"}
    ]);
});
// --> 
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **jquery.js**, **jquery.cross-slide.js**, are they in the correct location?
2. **src: "01.jpg"** till **src: "03.jpg"**, corresponds with the filename?

Comment: Thanks anyways, found other javascript to do the thing for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<body>
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="jquery.cross-slide.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<div id="crossslide" style="width:650px; height:100px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<!--
    $("#crossslide").crossSlide({
      speed: 45,
      fade:  1
    }, [
      { src: "01.jpg",    dir:"up"},
      { src: "02.jpg",    dir:"down"},
      { src: "03.jpg",    dir:"left"}
    ]);
// --> 
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's still not working. I only get a white blank page.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace { src: "01.jpg",    dir:"up"}, 
with {src:'01.jpg',    from:'top left x1', to: 'top right 0.1x', time: 45}, 
Make sure cross-slide.js exists

You can modify the CSS position tags of the code below:
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Cross Slide 1 </title>
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>  
  <script  type="text/javascript" src="crossSlide.js"></script> 
 </head>
 <body> 
   <div id="crossslide" style="width:650px; height:400px;"></div>
   <script>  

  $(function(){
  $("#crossslide").crossSlide({
  fade:1 }, [ 
    { src: 'rig.png',  alt: 'rig', from: '100% 80% 0.1x', to: '50% 50% 1x', time: 10},
{ src: 'sea.png',  alt: 'sea', from: '50% 50% 1x', to: '50% 50% .1x', time: 4},
{ src: 'world.png',  alt: 'world', from: 'top left 0.5x', to: 'top  right .1x',time:4}  

    ]);  });
     </script> 
     </body> 
 </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to put a Div to call the function in you code where you want the images to appear;

this works in my code, but only in development system.  I have not been able to make it work in Production even though the version of Centos and Apache are the same.  Still looking for a reason...